# about constant defined in a singleton class

Tags: swift, singleton

If I define a singleton in Swift 4:

```
public class MySingleton {
    static let shared = MySingleton()
}
```

Callers can access the singleton instance by `MySingleton.shared`.

If I add a constant field `school` in `MySingleton` :

```
public class MySingleton {
        static let shared = MySingleton()
        let school = School()
    }
```

Callers could access school by `MySingleton.shared.school`. Am I right that if all callers access `school` by this way, there would be only one instance of `School` in my iOS application?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create a singleton for your school?

```
class School {
    static let shared = School()

    private init() { }

}
```

instance of the school will be different every time I call `MySingleton().school`

Comment: Yes, I know I could do that as well, but I would like still to know the answer to my question. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, buy in my question, I mentioned if all callers access school by that way, meaning all callers access school by `MySingleton.shared.school`.  That `MySingleton().school` is not the point of the question.

Comment: If callers would call like that - yes school would be a singleton. Buuuut...)

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right that if all callers access school by this way, there would be only one instance of School in my iOS application?

In theory, maybe. In fact, maybe not. The problem is that `school` is an instance property. You say that callers *could* say `MySingleton.shared.school` — but the problem is, they might not. They could also say `MySingleton().school`. And if they do that, each one who says it will have a different School instance.

Comment: "Assume" is not "is", and "shouldn't" is not "won't", @Sh_Khan. A contract that is all in your head is no contract at all. It is up to the OP to _enforce_ the contract, and he hasn't. He left a hole big enough to drive a truck through.

Comment: Also if `School` is a struct then `var s = MySingleton.shared.school` will also be a different School instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the precondition of my question is actually callers only access school by `MySingleton.shared.school`.

Comment: @DanielT. Why will it? `MySingleton.shared` is a singleton, and `school` is a constant, so it's always the same School in that case.

Comment: @Leem But you did not _enforce_ that precondition. That's my point. If you did enforce it, the answer would be yes. But you didn't, so the answer is not yes.

Comment: @matt, you say if School is a struct then `var s = MySingleton.shared.school` will also be a different School instance??? I didn't know that, why it is a different instance? Could you please explain more?

Comment: OK, thanks, I am not sure who said that now, seems it is not you. But good to know that statement is wrong.

Comment: I said it. No two variables can hold the same struct object. At least conceptually. With copy-on-write going on under the covers it may be the same instance. However, if you do `var s = MySingleton.shared.school` and then `s.someMutatingOp()` you will *not* be changing the singleton's school instance (if School is a struct.) At that point, you will have created a second `School` instance.

Comment: @DanielT. Ah, ok. I was assuming, perhaps wrongly, that School was a class just like MySingleton. After all, there is no such _thing_ as a "singleton struct" — they are not "shared" in _any_ sense, for just the reason you gave. So that would be a very silly thing for the OP to ask (so I assumed he didn't ask it).

Comment: More assumptions. :-)

Comment: @DanielT. To be fair, that was the _only_ assumption my answer made. In fact, the whole _point_ of my answer is to warn the OP against assumptions. But you're right, the OP didn't give that info, so it _was_ an assumption. Oh, the irony.

Answer (score 0):

If all callers access `school` that way and no other instances are created, then it will be the only instance.

If `School` is a struct, then any attempt to store the school object in another variable will effectively create a new instance.

So for example:

```
var s = MySingleton.instance.school // where School is a struct.
```

In the above, `s` is conceptually a different instance than `MySingleton.instance.school` and changing one will *not* be reflected in the other.

Comment: If School is a struct, different callers call `MySingleton.shared.school` would yields a new instance of `School` ??? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: If the callers attempt to *store* the school in a local variable, it will be a different instance. Just making a call on it won't but  if you do `var s = MySingleton.shared.school` and then `s.someMutatingOp()` where `School` is a struct then you will *not* be changing the singleton's school instance. You will have a new instance. If something else changes the singleton's instance, it will *not* be reflected in the local School variable. `s` is effectively a different instance.